# How to figure out if a Treasury is on the run in Bloomberg Terminal

Tags: terminal, bloomberg

I'm new to Bloomberg Terminal. I've learned that sometimes it's important to use long-dated, or "off the run" Treasuries as opposed to "on the run" Treasuries. How do I know if a Treasury in Bloomberg is on or off the run?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Have you asked HELP HELP?